# Javascript function not working and the console says it isn't defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that I made in Javascript and My html file has

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

in it. The Javascript function on that page isn't working, and the console is saying the function is not defined. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, and any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
var player = 0;
var xvalue = 0;
var ovalue = 0;
function tic(a) 
{
    if(player === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'X';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 1;
        if(a === 'aa'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 1; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ab'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ac'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ba'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'bb'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 16; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'bc'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 32; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ca'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 64; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'cb'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 128; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'cc'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++; ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        if(xvalue === 448){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 7){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 56){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 273){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 84){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 73){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 146){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 292){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'O';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors. The console (FF) says `SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control`. Basically all your `for` loops are syntactically incorrect. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i run your script i get : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

So , you error in  loops:

```
 for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++; ){
```

the right way is :

```
 for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++ ){
```

REmove `;`

Hence , the right code is :

```
var player = 0;
var xvalue = 0;
var ovalue = 0;
function tic(a) 
{
    if(player === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'X';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 1;
        if(a === 'aa'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 1; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ab'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ac'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ba'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'bb'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 16; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'bc'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 32; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ca'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 64; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'cb'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 128; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'cc'){
            var i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++ ){
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        if(xvalue === 448){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 7){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 56){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 273){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 84){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 73){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 146){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
        else if(xvalue === 292){
            alert("player 1 wins!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'O';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax for For loop** is

```
for(initialization;condition;increment)
```

you have used wrong Syntax in every `for` loop

So Remove  `;`  after increment

```
for(i = 1; i <= 64; i++; )
```

to

```
for(i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
```